# JS Call Stack with context

Tags: javascript

All,

I have a bit of code that is essentially,

```
function b(){
    console.log(this);
}

function a(){
    console.log(this);
    b();
}

Window.call(context, a);
```

The output looks like:

```
Object(context)
Window
```

It looks like the nonstandard context is only preserved when calling call, all subroutines where a context is not specified are called with the original context. Is there any way to invoke a function with context, having its entire execution stack occupy that same context?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.call()` or `.apply()`:

```
function a(){
    console.log(this);
    b.call(this);
}
```

You cannot flip the runtime into a mode wherein it implicitly does that, so the direct answer to your question is "no".

If you have a bunch of functions and want to create versions that always have some particular value for `this`, you can use `.bind()`:

```
function b(){
    console.log(this);
}

function a(){
    console.log(this);
    b();
}

a = a.bind(context), b = b.bind(context);
a(); // logs context from both functions
```

That'd be a pretty unusual thing to do but it would work. You'd be out of luck if you wanted to use the functions with a different object.

Comment: Does using bind have the same limitations? I'm trying to write classes that have a number of internal methods not accessible from outside the class. I want the available methods to be able to call these to access/update internal state.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple rule in Javascript.  Every function call in Javascript sets a new value for `this`.  If you aren't making a method call such as `obj.method()` or using `.call()` or `.apply()`, then `this` is set back to the Global object or to `undefined` in strict mode.

So, if you want to specifically control the value of `this` in either of your function calls, then you will need to use `.call()` or `.apply()` or perhaps even `.bind()`.  There is no magic mode you can put Javascript in that will "preserve" `this` when you call other functions.  It just doesn't work that way.

Architecturally, if you really want a specific value of `this` for several functions, then perhaps they should be methods on a common object because calling `obj.method()` will automatically set `this` to `obj` or you can use `.call()` or `.apply()` to manually specify what you want the `this` value to be for any function call.

In your code example, you could change:

```
function a(){
    console.log(this);
    b();
}
```

to this:

```
function a(){
    console.log(this);
    b.call(this);
}
```

And, `b()` would get executed with the same value of `this` as `a()`.

Comment: The reason I don't want to do this is that I have to then use call all the way down. If B was to call any other methods those would have to all be altered to also change context. This would make using any library methods nearly impossible...

Comment: @Goldfish - You're trying to do structure things in some way that runs against the grain of how Javascript works.  You need to rethink what you're trying to do to align with how Javascript works.  As I said, if you want all your functions to share a common `this` value, then make them methods on an object and call them with `obj.method()`.  That's how JS works.  `this` IS reset on every plain function call.  Nothing you can do to change that other than use one of the methods we've outlined.